# Recursive loops

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-loop, probability

The question is to return the probability of, if you start with 10,000 and need to get to 20,000, and you bet 1,000 each time (probability of reaching 20,000 before you get to 0). You have 50-50 change of win or loss.

```
public static double roulette( double start, double end, double bet) {

    if (start >= end) return 1;
    if (start <= 0) return 0;

        return .5*roulette(start+2*bet,end,bet) + .5*roulette(start-bet,end,bet);
}
```

but it gets stuck on an infinite loop because some recursive calls will start again. As in if I hit a call in which start = 11,000, it will go back to 10,000 and create a loop. How do I prevent this?

Comment: is your program returning correct probability for smaller inputs ? for limits say 1000 - 2000 ?

Comment: Does the solution have to be recursive?

Comment: I would suggest trying to either step through your code with a debugger, or adding print statements so you can see what is actually happening.  Tough for anyone here to debug your code just based on the question.

Comment: Yes, this is fine for any recursive call that does not get back to the original function. let's say start = 100, end = 200, bet = 50. then it will call on 200 and return 1, then on 150, it can finish the +100 call and return 1, but then it will gets to 150-50 = 100 and get stuck since it's the beginning.

Comment: The OP explained the exact problem with the code - `roulette(10000, 20000, 1000)` calls `roulette(11000, 20000, 1000)` which calls `roulette(10000, 20000, 1000)`. hence the infinite loop.

Comment: i'll take a very simple one. start = 2, end = 3, bet = 1. So, it calls f(2) =  .5*f(2 + 2*1) + .5*f(2-1) = .5*f(4) + .5*f(1). f(4) = 1 since 4 >=3. Now evaluate .5*f(1) = .25*f(-1) + .25*f(2). f(-1) = 0, but it actually gets stuck on f(2). This is what causes the loop. I want to somehow tell the program that when it's trying to evaluate f(2) = .5*1 + .25*f(2), to subtract like terms, and evaluate .75*f(2) = .5. Otherwise it just turns into a loop.

Comment: @Eran it does not have to be recursive. If you have another idea of a solution i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Why don't you just make it in a single loop?

Comment: The probability is relevant to the number of times you bet. So you should set a limited bet number, if the number reaches 0 or your current money becomes less than bet, then the probability is zero, otherwise add up all probabilities which you ended up with  money more than end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the specific query regarding "probability of reaching 20,000 before you get to 0", this can be solved as a [Random Walk over a one dimensional graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) as explained:

> "If a and b are positive integers, then the expected number of steps until a one-dimensional simple random walk starting at 0 first hits b or −a is ab. The probability that this walk will hit b before −a is b/(a+b), which can be derived from the fact that simple random walk is a martingale."

Given, the walk origin = 10000, a=10000 (distance from 0), b=10000 (distance from 20000), & step-size =1000:
The probability to reach b before -a = 10000/(10000 + 10000) = 1/2.

Not sure if that's all that you wanted to implement, which would be a one line return statement.

On the other hand, the given implementation will end-up exploring the entire space of possible solutions (i.e. all possible ways of reaching 0 or 20000). Refer to the Probabilities & Pascal triangles section in the [RandomWalk.pdf](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/RandomWalk.pdf) for the pattern of growth on this & its long run time. Your implementation has started its exploration along the right most branch/ diagonal of the pascal triangle, & goes on to explore all possible branches.

Instead, an alternative could be to try to implement a method that computes the probability of reaching 20000 (or 0) the first time (& not in all possible ways) & then break. Making the choice of going down the right (win) or left branch (loss) [at random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Average the numbers over a few runs & that should be fairly close to the probabilities, ~1/2 as computed above.

Interestingly, the expected distance covered in a random walk after n steps = sqrt(n). This can be used to estimate the number of iterations or recursive calls (complexity) necessary for a properly implemented algorithm to reach 20000 or 0.
In this case, the distance n = ((20000-10000)/1000) = 10, it should require about n*n = 100 steps/ iterations on an average.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggested iterative solution (I'm leaving the implementation to you):

To make it shorter, let's find `roulette(10,20,1)` (which is equivalent to your `roulette(10000,20000,1000)`). Let's denote `roulette(10,20,1)` with `r(10)`.

Now, let's calculate `r(i)` where `i` goes from `0` to `20`.

- r(0) = 0 - i.e. no chance to win if you have no money left.
- r(20) = 1 - since it means you won.

Now let's compute the other `r(i)`s:

- r(1) = 0.5 * r(2) + 0.5 * r(0) = 0.5 * r(2) + 0 = 1/2 * r(2)
- r(2) = 0.5 * r(3) + 0.5 * r(1) = 0.5 * r(3) + 0.5 * (0.5 * r(2))

which means

- r(2) = 2/3 * r(3)

If you continue with these calculations, you'll find out that

- r(3) = 3/4 * r(4)
- r(4) = 4/5 * r(5)

...

- r(18) = 18/19 * r(19)
- r(19) = 19/20 * r(20) = 19/20 * 1 = 19/20

Now that we found `r(19)`, we can find `r(18)`:

- r(18) = 18/19 * 19/20 = 18/20
- r(17) = 17/18 * r(18) = 17/18 * 18/20 = 17/20

...

- r(10) = 10/20 = 0.5

Hence if you start with 10000 and need to get to 20000, and you bet 1000 each time, you have a 50% chance to reach 20000.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, the probability is a sum of all probabilities which ended up with `start >= end` or `left < 0`.

```
static double roulette(double start, double end, double bet, int left) {
    if (start >= end && left >= 0)
        return 1; // you definitely win.
    if (start < bet || left < 0)
        return 0; // you cannot win.
    double win = 0.5 * roulette(start + bet, end, bet, left - 1);
    double lose = 0.5 * roulette(start - bet, end, bet, left - 1);
    return win + lose; // you get a 0.5-0.5 to win or lose.
}
```

For example, assume `start` is 100, `end` is 200, `bet` is 50.
if the total number is 2, there is only one way: 100->150->200 which is a probability of 0.25. But if the total number is 4, you can have those ways to win: 100->150->200, 100->150->100->150->200, 100->50->100->150->200. The probability to win is 0.375.